# How to show two fragment in one activity with Jetpack Navigation lib

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, fragment

How to show two fragments in one activity using Navigation in Android?

I have added FragmentContainerView with nav_graph.xml in MainActivity.xml
where nav_graph.xml has firstFragment as a start destination. But I want two fragment on the MainActivity.xml so, how to do?

As two fragments are on same level in activity, so, no any startDestination.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Suppose we have two fragment, FragmentOne and FragmentTwo and single Activity name like, MainActivity.

Comment: What is your ask here exactly? Do you want to dynamically set primary fragment to the nav graph ?

Comment: If I get you right, you can add n of fragments in a single graph.

Comment: https://www.imagevenue.com/ME16892F

**Main Activity has two fragment. FragmnetA and FragmentB. How can I achieve this by Navigation lib ?**

Comment: The question is not clear. Please [edit] the question to add a clear description of what is wanted. Adding dribs and drabs in comments is not helpful. Images are only useful to add clarification, the main detail must be described (in text or code) in the question.